# Transpose a SQL / SAS table row to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset created in SAS through PROC SQL based on Premier League results and need to transpose the column Result to multiple individual columns, while grouping each Team to only one row. At present my table looks like:

| Team | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Arsenal | D |
| Arsenal | L |
| Arsenal | D |
| Arsenal | W |
| Chelsea | L |
| Chelsea | D |

And I'm trying to make it look like:

| Team | Form |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arsenal | D | L | D | W |
| Chelsea | L | D | W | W |
| Tottenham | D | W | L | W |
| Arsenal | W | W | L | L |

The above are just short examples i.e, the table contains the form of every Premier League team over the last 6 weeks.

Thank you!

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your rearrangement looks like it is dependent on some ordering of the rows, so it cannot be done.  Happily, SAS data sets *are ordered*, so you can use a `data step` or `proc` to do this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks Gordon - I really appreciate the quick response! As you mentioned, I managed to solve the issue using PROC TRANSPOSE.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to sort the data and then add an id column which will help us to transpose the dataset. Try this and see if it works. I didn't have the time to test the solution as I don't have the access to SAS anymore.

```
proc sort data=dataset;
by Team;
run;

data dataset;
set dataset;
by Team;
if first.Team then New_column=0;
New_column+1;
run;

proc transpose data= dataset out= dataset_out(drop=_NAME_) prefix= Form_;
by Team;
var Form;
id New_column;
run;
```